# Angular generate component throws error 'Cannot find module 'chownr''

Tags: angular-cli

I have an angular project generated using angular cli version 7+. Generating components using the ng g c componentName throws an error: 'Cannot find module 'chownr''.
I have no Idea what is happening here. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall module with:

```
npm uninstall chownr
```

Close VSCode and open again, go to node_modules folder in your project and delete a folder called like ".chownr-DELETE".

Make installation of the module again.

```
npm install chownr
```

And launch again the Angular app